# saving image from Blender to a specific path

Tags: python, scripting, image

I'm trying to save an image to a path which the user can choose, but I always get the error-message:

`line 64, in execute
    image.save_render(path+"output/Image0"+str(counter)+".png", scene)
    RuntimeError: Error: Could not write image '//../../../testOut/output/Image00.png'`

here's how the var path is set:

```
path = bpy.props.StringProperty(default="/", subtype="FILE_PATH")
```

[...]

```
path = self.path

scene.render.image_settings.file_format='PNG'
image.save_render(path+"output/Image0"+str(counter)+".png", scene)
```

Answer (score 7):

`image.save_render()` cannot use relative paths, which are returned by default by "FILE_PATH" StringProperties. To convert the path to absolute, you can simply do:

```
path = bpy.path.abspath(self.path)
```

Comment: @user5602 If this answer has satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it :)